# inserting elements in output xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

i have the following xml document:

```
<config>
  <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
  <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
 </config>
```

I need to check if properties with names "prop3", "prop4", "prop5" exist and if they don't, I need to add them under config keeping the existing elements.  The elements with these properties may exist in which case, I need to change their values.  Can someone help, please?

Comment: please format your xml part with code block, so we can actually see it!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple solution based on the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- using and overriding the identity rule. Extensive explanation is provided. – Dimitre Novatchev 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample xsl stylesheet for such a functionality:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <config>
            <xsl:for-each select="config/property">
                <!-- Fills up from 1 until first prop -->
                <xsl:if test="string(number(substring(preceding-sibling::property/@name,5,1) + 1)) = 'NaN' and number(substring(@name,5,1)) &gt; 1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="filler">
                        <xsl:with-param name="from" select="1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="until" select="number(substring(@name,5,1))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <!-- Fills up the gaps -->
                <xsl:if test="number(substring(@name,5,1)) &gt; number(substring(preceding-sibling::property/@name,5,1) + 1)">
                    <xsl:call-template name="filler">
                        <xsl:with-param name="from" select="number(substring(preceding-sibling::property/@name,5,1) + 1)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="until" select="number(substring(@name,5,1))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <!-- copies the current node -->
                <property>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </property>
                <!-- Fills up to 5 from last prop -->
                <xsl:if test="substring(following-sibling::property/@name, 1, 4) != 'prop'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="filler">
                        <xsl:with-param name="from" select="number(substring(@name,5,1)) + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="until" select="6"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </config>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="filler" match="property">
        <xsl:param name="from"/>
        <xsl:param name="until"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$from &lt; $until">
                <property>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('prop', $from)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('val ', $from)"/>
                </property>
                <xsl:call-template name="filler">
                    <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from + 1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="until" select="$until"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This piece of code basically fills up the xml to make sure that it contains all the values from prop1 to prop5.

Not that sophisticated -since i don't know the exact purpose-, but maybe it will help you out, and you can generalize it for your needs.

This way the output will be

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<config>
  <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
  <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
  <property name="prop3">val 3</property>
  <property name="prop4">val 4</property>
  <property name="prop5">val 5</property>
</config>
```

for any of the following inputs:

```
<config>
    <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
    <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
</config>

<config>
    <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
</config>

<config>
    <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
    <property name="prop4">val 4</property>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:replacements>
    <property name="prop3">Newval 3</property>
    <property name="prop4">Newval 4</property>
    <property name="prop5">Newval 5</property>
 </my:replacements>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select=
  "document('')/*/my:replacements/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "property
    [@name
    =
     document('')/*/my:replacements/*/@name
    ]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$vReps"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<config>
    <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
    <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
</config>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result:**

```
<config>
  <property name="prop1">val 1</property>
  <property name="prop2">val 2</property>
  <property name="prop3" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">Newval 3</property>
  <property name="prop4" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">Newval 4</property>
  <property name="prop5" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">Newval 5</property>
</config>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".
2. The overriding template for any `property` element with `name` attribute having the value of one of the `name` attributes of the `my:replacements/property` elements, in effects deletes any such element from the document (because of the empty body of the template.
3. The overriding template that matches the top element of the document shallow-copies it, then copies its attributes and applies templates to all of its descendent nodes (in effect copying all of them except those in 2. above. Finally, it copies all replacement elements that are children of the embedded `my:replacements` element.
4. The namespace nodes that appear in the newly copied replacement elements will disappear when these replacement elements are in a separate XML document (not in the XSLT stylesheet as is now done solely for convenience).

**Do note**: The main idea of this solution is that replacing elements when they exist or adding elements when they don't exist -- this is just the same as (without checking for existence) copying the new elements overwriting any existing elements.

Comment: +1 Better answer. It would be more simple without inline data and literal result elements instead.

Comment: @Alejandro: The whole idea is for the XSLT code not to need to be changed at all -- just to edit the external document that contains the reps. Having inline literal-result elements violates this requirement.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre.  It worked for what I had asked, however there's one detail I missed..I need to retrieve "Newval 3", "Newval 4" from the "xsl" namespace of this xslt document.  They are defined as <xsl:param name="NewVal 3"/>
    <xsl:param name="NewVal 4"/> etc
    the values are supplied by another document that calls this xslt . If I do <xsl:value-of select="$NewVal 3"/> instead of "NewVal 3", I don't see the actual value.  I see this statement as is.  How should I code it so I see the value...Thanks again!

Comment: @krishna23: I think the parameter name should be `prop3` and only its value should be `NewVal 3`. The string `NewVal 3` contains a space and is not a valid name in XML/XPath/XSLT

Comment: You are right.  It is "prop3".  I mistyped it.  I still don't see the value though.  The output I see is "<property name="prop3"><xsl:value-of select="$prop3"/></property>" but what I want is "<property name="prop3">NewVal 3</property>"